# Copy folder recursively in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Is there an easier way to copy a folder and all its content without manually doing a sequence of `fs.readir`, `fs.readfile`, `fs.writefile` recursively?

I am just wondering if I'm missing a function which would ideally work like this:

```
fs.copy("/path/to/source/folder", "/path/to/destination/folder");
```

---

*Regarding this historic question. Note that `fs.cp` and `fs.cpSync` can copy folders recursively and are available in Node v16+*

Comment: Is there a way to do this without any modules? Maybe a recursive function / code snip-it?

Comment: @Sukima - See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21321485/552792).

Comment: what do you mean by "without manually" and without modules?. Are you asking for a native bash command or any Nodejs built-in library? if yes, there isn't such a thing yet. The options are to reinvent the wheel and create a recursive function or use a third party wheel

Comment: nowadays it's simply **fs.cpSync** that's all it is, simple

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Since Node v16.7.0 it is possible to use [`fs.cp`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fscpsrc-dest-options-callback) or [`fs.cpSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fscpsyncsrc-dest-options) function.

```js
fs.cp(src, dest, {recursive: true}, (err) => {/* callback */});
// Or
fs.cpSync(src, dest, {recursive: true});
```

Current stability (in Node v21.1.0) is [Experimental](https://nodejs.org/api/documentation.html#stability-index).

Comment: `node -e "const fs = require('fs');fs.cp(...);"` is super handy in package.json scripts

Comment: @TamusJRoyce: If you like that, you'll love Node's the `-r` (`--require`) parameter.

Comment: I've only used -r with external scripts. How can -r be used with inline scripts?

Comment: I want to use that, but, um, as the link says, "_Stability: 1 - Experimental. The feature is not subject to semantic versioning rules. Non-backward compatible changes or removal may occur in any future release. Use of the feature is not recommended in production environments._"

Answer (score 113):

It looks like [**ncp**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ncp) and [**wrench**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wrench) both are no longer maintained. Probably the best option is to use [**fs-extra**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra)

The Developer of Wrench directs users to use `fs-extra` as he has deprecated his library

**copySync** & **moveSync** both will copy and move folders even if they have files or subfolders and you can easily move or copy files using it

```js
const fse = require('fs-extra');

const srcDir = `path/to/file`;
const destDir = `path/to/destination/directory`;
                                 
// To copy a folder or file, select overwrite accordingly
try {
  fse.copySync(srcDir, destDir, { overwrite: true|false })
  console.log('success!')
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
}
```

***OR***

```js
// To Move a folder or file, select overwrite accordingly
try {
  fs.moveSync(srcDir, destDir, { overwrite: true|false })
  console.log('success!')
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
}
```

Comment: fse copySync does not take callbacks: https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/HEAD/docs/copy-sync.md. If you want to detect error you should do try-catch:  `try { fse.copySync('/tmp/myfile', '/tmp/mynewfile'); console.log('success!');} catch (err) {  console.error(err);}`

Comment: `copySync`'s arguments have changed, third arg is an options object, not a callback: https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/master/docs/copy-sync.md

Comment: FYI node has experimental `fs.cp` https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_cp_src_dest_options, which
 
> "Asynchronously copies the entire directory structure from src to dest, including subdirectories and files."

Comment: Hi @GeorgiyBukharov It will help but its still in experimental in Node v16.7.0 as of Now. 


It will be easy to use in future versions of node.

Comment: just to clarify, copySync it accepts either opts object or function according to it's implementation. However the function as third parameter is treated as filter option, not a callback.

Comment: There's no reason to add a callback to a `_Sync` function--just use the main-line code.

Answer (score 87):

This is my approach to solve this problem without any extra modules. Just using the built-in `fs` and `path` modules.

**Note:** This does use the read / write functions of fs, so it does not copy any meta data (time of creation, etc.). As of Node.js 8.5 there is a `copyFileSync` function available which calls the OS copy functions and therefore also copies meta data. I did not test them yet, but it should work to just replace them. (See https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_copyfilesync_src_dest_flags)

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

function copyFileSync( source, target ) {

    var targetFile = target;

    // If target is a directory, a new file with the same name will be created
    if ( fs.existsSync( target ) ) {
        if ( fs.lstatSync( target ).isDirectory() ) {
            targetFile = path.join( target, path.basename( source ) );
        }
    }

    fs.writeFileSync(targetFile, fs.readFileSync(source));
}

function copyFolderRecursiveSync( source, target ) {
    var files = [];

    // Check if folder needs to be created or integrated
    var targetFolder = path.join( target, path.basename( source ) );
    if ( !fs.existsSync( targetFolder ) ) {
        fs.mkdirSync( targetFolder );
    }

    // Copy
    if ( fs.lstatSync( source ).isDirectory() ) {
        files = fs.readdirSync( source );
        files.forEach( function ( file ) {
            var curSource = path.join( source, file );
            if ( fs.lstatSync( curSource ).isDirectory() ) {
                copyFolderRecursiveSync( curSource, targetFolder );
            } else {
                copyFileSync( curSource, targetFolder );
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't copy folders if they have space in their names

Comment: For me it does copy folders with spaces in their names. Maybe it was caused by the error corrected by @victor . As i am using this function quite regularly (in the current state, as i forgot to update the very same correction victor did), i am quite sure that it does work in general.

Comment: @SimonZyx, `fs.createReadStream` is not synchronous. Changing it to `  fs.writeFileSync(target, fs.readFileSync(source));` will make it so.

Comment: this won't work if the source is a file, only works for directories.

Comment: This doesn't actually copy files. It reads them then writes them. That's not copying. Copying includes creation date as well as other meta data streams that both Windows and MacOS support and are not copied by this code. As of node 8.5 you should call `fs.copy` or `fs.copySync` as they actual calls the OS level copy functions in MacOS and Windows and so actually copy files.

Comment: @gman: You are right that it does not copy the meta data, but it is still a copy in a sense of "it copies the content". I will include this in the answer. I don't see a `fs.copy` in the current node documentation (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).
Are you sure you don't use fs-extra? This does copy the meta data, but does not use the os level copy (see https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/master/lib/copy/copy.js)

Comment: sorry it's [`fs.copyFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_copyfile_src_dest_flags_callback) and if your dig through the node source you'll see on Mac and Windows they call the OS specific function to copy a file

Comment: I know files have meta data, so using '''copyFile''' is a method that copies meta data. A question I have is do folders contain meta data? If they do, then what is a method of copying a folder keeping the meta data?

Answer (score 78):

Here's a function that recursively copies a directory and its contents to another directory:

```js
const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")

/**
 * Look ma, it's cp -R.
 * @param {string} src  The path to the thing to copy.
 * @param {string} dest The path to the new copy.
 */
var copyRecursiveSync = function(src, dest) {
  var exists = fs.existsSync(src);
  var stats = exists && fs.statSync(src);
  var isDirectory = exists && stats.isDirectory();
  if (isDirectory) {
    fs.mkdirSync(dest);
    fs.readdirSync(src).forEach(function(childItemName) {
      copyRecursiveSync(path.join(src, childItemName),
                        path.join(dest, childItemName));
    });
  } else {
    fs.copyFileSync(src, dest);
  }
};
```

Comment: Even if you would insert a real copy function you should not follow symbolic links (use `fs.lstatSync` instead of `fs.statSync`)

Comment: what might have caused this confusion is that fs.unlink deletes files, but fs.link doesn't copy but link.

Comment: @SimonSeyock: is right .. IT is  `linking` not copying .. The issue is when you modify the content of linked file , the original file will change too.

Answer (score 56):

There are some modules that support copying folders with their content. The most popular would be [wrench.js](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/wrench-js):

```
// Deep-copy an existing directory
wrench.copyDirSyncRecursive('directory_to_copy', 'location_where_copy_should_end_up');
```

An alternative would be [node-fs-extra](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra):

```
fs.copy('/tmp/mydir', '/tmp/mynewdir', function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log("success!");
  }
}); // Copies directory, even if it has subdirectories or files
```

Comment: wrench fails if directory to copy contains a symbolic link

Comment: it also fails on Windows if the directory already exists, [ncp](https://npmjs.org/package/ncp) worked right out of the bag.

Comment: node-fs-extra worked for me. It inherits the original fs and I liked it's way of handling the process. Less code to update in the app.

Comment: Please note that `wrench` has been deprecated and should be replaced by `node-fs-extra` (https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra)

Comment: Wrench doesn't actually copy files. It reads them then writes them, then copies their date. That's not copying. Copying includes other meta data streams that both Windows and MacOS support and are not copied by wrench.

Answer (score 39):

This is how I would do it personally:

```
function copyFolderSync(from, to) {
    fs.mkdirSync(to);
    fs.readdirSync(from).forEach(element => {
        if (fs.lstatSync(path.join(from, element)).isFile()) {
            fs.copyFileSync(path.join(from, element), path.join(to, element));
        } else {
            copyFolderSync(path.join(from, element), path.join(to, element));
        }
    });
}
```

It works for folders and files.

Comment: This solution is terse and straightforward. This would be nearly exactly how I'd do it, so a +1 from me. You should improve your answer with comments in your code and describe why this solution is preferred over others and what drawbacks it may have. -- Also update what modules it requires. ("path", "fs")

Comment: check if the folder exists at the top...will save lives ;-) if (!fs.existsSync(to)) fs.mkdirSync(to);

Comment: This is a great snippet, no external dependencies needed.  Node.js should be able to copy directories on its own without external add-ons, and it is, like this code shows.   I wonder, would it be easy to extend this to work asynchronously?

Answer (score 29):

**For a Linux/Unix OS, you can use the shell syntax**

```
const shell = require('child_process').execSync;

const src = `/path/src`;
const dist = `/path/dist`;

shell(`mkdir -p ${dist}`);
shell(`cp -r ${src}/* ${dist}`);
```

That's it!

Comment: since nodejs runs on OSX/linux/windows this only is the answer for 2 not all 3.

Comment: @mjwrazor: You can run NodeJS in Linux container (Virtualized Env) even the host is Windows.

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI what if you are running on windows server.

Comment: That's why I started the answer by "For linux/unix OS, you can use the shell syntax.." 

Comment: windows has shell commands to copy directories im sure, could just add a condition or change based on relevant host

Comment: @Ridderhoff Run Docker Daemon in Windows, then Run Node App in container which is by default a linux container

Comment: A cross-platform (Windows included) solution does exist:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs .  It should be useful for many other things besides directory-copying as well

Comment: This is not copying within node. In other words, node is not abstracting the copying. There is no guarantee this will be ran by others in a posix compliant environment (wsl1 & git bash/MSYS2 are posix, but not linux or unix).

Comment: yes @TamusJRoyce i know.. but better than nothing.. use (if os == "linux") { ...do .. }

Answer (score 22):

The fs-extra module works like a charm.

Install fs-extra:

```
$ npm install fs-extra
```

The following is the program to copy a source directory to a destination directory.

```
// Include the fs-extra package
var fs = require("fs-extra");

var source = 'folderA'
var destination = 'folderB'

// Copy the source folder to the destination
fs.copy(source, destination, function (err) {
    if (err){
        console.log('An error occurred while copying the folder.')
        return console.error(err)
    }
    console.log('Copy completed!')
});
```

#### References

fs-extra: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra

Example: [Node.js Tutorial](https://www.tutorialkart.com/nodejs/nodejs-tutorial/) - [Node.js Copy a Folder](https://www.tutorialkart.com/nodejs/node-js-copy-a-folder/)

Comment: does this process replace the directory or merge with it?

Answer (score 18):

This is pretty easy with Node.js 10:

```
const Path = require('path');
const FSP = require('fs').promises;

async function copyDir(src,dest) {
    const entries = await FSP.readdir(src, {withFileTypes: true});
    await FSP.mkdir(dest);
    for(let entry of entries) {
        const srcPath = Path.join(src, entry.name);
        const destPath = Path.join(dest, entry.name);
        if(entry.isDirectory()) {
            await copyDir(srcPath, destPath);
        } else {
            await FSP.copyFile(srcPath, destPath);
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes `dest` does not exist.

Comment: We can get this to work in Node 8.x by using `require('util').promisify` with `fs.mkdir` and `fs.copyFile` instead of `require('fs').promises`, which is still experimental at v11.1.

Comment: @sntran Does 8.x have the `withFileTypes` option? Because that saves you a `stat` call

Comment: Unfortunately, 8.x does not have `withFileTypes` option.

Comment: @SơnTrần-Nguyễn 8.x reaches end of life on December 31, 2019 -- might be time to upgrade :-)

Answer (score 15):

I know so many answers are already here, but no one answered it in a simple way.

Regarding fs-exra [official documentation](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/master/docs/copy-sync.md), you can do it very easy.

```
const fs = require('fs-extra')

// Copy file
fs.copySync('/tmp/myfile', '/tmp/mynewfile')

// Copy directory, even if it has subdirectories or files
fs.copySync('/tmp/mydir', '/tmp/mynewdir')
```

Comment: make sure to set recursive option.  fs.copySync('/tmp/mydir', '/tmp/mynewdir',{ recursive: true })

Comment: I can't find option`{ recursive: true }` from [github doc](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/master/docs/copy-sync.md) you mentioned, Don't know is it work.

Comment: I guess we are talking about fs-extra, but your github link points to node-fs-extra. Could be different library?

Comment: @DheerajKumar, It shows node-fs-extra in github but fs-extra in [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra). I don't know both are same please refer package from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra)

Comment: Does fs-extra replace fs?

Answer (score 9):

I created a small working example that copies a source folder to another destination folder in just a few steps (based on [shift66's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786160/copy-folder-recursively-in-node-js/13786224#13786224) using ncp):

**Step 1 - Install ncp module:**

```
npm install ncp --save
```

**Step 2 - create copy.js (modify the *srcPath* and *destPath* variables to whatever you need):**

```
var path = require('path');
var ncp = require('ncp').ncp;

ncp.limit = 16;

var srcPath = path.dirname(require.main.filename); // Current folder
var destPath = '/path/to/destination/folder'; // Any destination folder

console.log('Copying files...');
ncp(srcPath, destPath, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  console.log('Copying files complete.');
});
```

**Step 3 - run**

```
node copy.js
```

Answer (score 7):

The one with **symbolic link** support:

```js
const path = require("path");
const {
  existsSync,
  mkdirSync,
  readdirSync,
  lstatSync,
  copyFileSync,
  symlinkSync,
  readlinkSync,
} = require("fs");

export function copyFolderSync(src, dest) {
  if (!existsSync(dest)) {
    mkdirSync(dest);
  }

  readdirSync(src).forEach((entry) => {
    const srcPath = path.join(src, entry);
    const destPath = path.join(dest, entry);
    const stat = lstatSync(srcPath);

    if (stat.isFile()) {
      copyFileSync(srcPath, destPath);
    } else if (stat.isDirectory()) {
      copyFolderSync(srcPath, destPath);
    } else if (stat.isSymbolicLink()) {
      symlinkSync(readlinkSync(srcPath), destPath);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since Node v16.7.0:

```js
import { cp } from 'fs/promises';
await cp(
  new URL('../path/to/src/', import.meta.url),
  new URL('../path/to/dest/', import.meta.url), {
    recursive: true,
  }
);
```

Note carefully the use of `recursive: true`. This prevents an `ERR_FS_EISDIR` error.

Read more on the [Node Filesystem](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/fs.html#fspromisescpsrc-dest-options) documentation

Answer (score 4):

[Mallikarjun M, thank you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786160/copy-folder-recursively-in-node-js/46685431#46685431)!

**fs-extra** did the thing and it can even return a **Promise** if you do not provide a callback! :)

```
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs-extra')

let source = path.resolve( __dirname, 'folderA')
let destination = path.resolve( __dirname, 'folderB')

fs.copy(source, destination)
  .then(() => console.log('Copy completed!'))
  .catch( err => {
    console.log('An error occurred while copying the folder.')
    return console.error(err)
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried fs-extra and copy-dir to copy-folder-recursively. but I want it to

1. work normally (copy-dir throws an unreasonable error)
2. provide two arguments in filter: filepath and filetype (fs-extra does't tell filetype)
3. have a dir-to-subdir check and a dir-to-file check

So I wrote my own:

```
// Node.js module for Node.js 8.6+
var path = require("path");
var fs = require("fs");

function copyDirSync(src, dest, options) {
  var srcPath = path.resolve(src);
  var destPath = path.resolve(dest);
  if(path.relative(srcPath, destPath).charAt(0) != ".")
    throw new Error("dest path must be out of src path");
  var settings = Object.assign(Object.create(copyDirSync.options), options);
  copyDirSync0(srcPath, destPath, settings);
  function copyDirSync0(srcPath, destPath, settings) {
    var files = fs.readdirSync(srcPath);
    if (!fs.existsSync(destPath)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(destPath);
    }else if(!fs.lstatSync(destPath).isDirectory()) {
      if(settings.overwrite)
        throw new Error(`Cannot overwrite non-directory '${destPath}' with directory '${srcPath}'.`);
      return;
    }
    files.forEach(function(filename) {
      var childSrcPath = path.join(srcPath, filename);
      var childDestPath = path.join(destPath, filename);
      var type = fs.lstatSync(childSrcPath).isDirectory() ? "directory" : "file";
      if(!settings.filter(childSrcPath, type))
        return;
      if (type == "directory") {
        copyDirSync0(childSrcPath, childDestPath, settings);
      } else {
        fs.copyFileSync(childSrcPath, childDestPath, settings.overwrite ? 0 : fs.constants.COPYFILE_EXCL);
        if(!settings.preserveFileDate)
          fs.futimesSync(childDestPath, Date.now(), Date.now());
      }
    });
  }
}
copyDirSync.options = {
  overwrite: true,
  preserveFileDate: true,
  filter: function(filepath, type) {
    return true;
  }
};
```

And a similar function, *mkdirs*, which is an alternative to mkdirp:

```
function mkdirsSync(dest) {
  var destPath = path.resolve(dest);
  mkdirsSync0(destPath);
  function mkdirsSync0(destPath) {
    var parentPath = path.dirname(destPath);
    if(parentPath == destPath)
      throw new Error(`cannot mkdir ${destPath}, invalid root`);
    if (!fs.existsSync(destPath)) {
      mkdirsSync0(parentPath);
      fs.mkdirSync(destPath);
    }else if(!fs.lstatSync(destPath).isDirectory()) {
      throw new Error(`cannot mkdir ${destPath}, a file already exists there`);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this function for both copying (copyFileSync) or moving (renameSync) files recursively between directories:

```
// Copy files
copyDirectoryRecursiveSync(sourceDir, targetDir);
// Move files
copyDirectoryRecursiveSync(sourceDir, targetDir, true);


function copyDirectoryRecursiveSync(source, target, move) {
    if (!fs.lstatSync(source).isDirectory())
        return;

    var operation = move ? fs.renameSync : fs.copyFileSync;
    fs.readdirSync(source).forEach(function (itemName) {
        var sourcePath = path.join(source, itemName);
        var targetPath = path.join(target, itemName);

        if (fs.lstatSync(sourcePath).isDirectory()) {
            fs.mkdirSync(targetPath);
            copyDirectoryRecursiveSync(sourcePath, targetPath);
        }
        else {
            operation(sourcePath, targetPath);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Be careful when picking your package. Some packages like copy-dir does not support copying large files more than 0X1FFFFFE8 characters (about 537 MB) long.

It will throw some error like:

> buffer.js:630 Uncaught Error: Cannot create a string longer than 0x1fffffe8 characters

I have experienced something like this in one of my projects. Ultimately, I had to change the package I was using and adjust a lot of code. I would say that this is not a very pleasant experience.

If multiple source and multiple destination copies are desired, you can use [better-copy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-copy) and write something like this:

```js
// Copy from multiple source into a directory
bCopy(['/path/to/your/folder1', '/path/to/some/file.txt'], '/path/to/destination/folder');
```

Or even:

```
// Copy from multiple source into multiple destination
bCopy(['/path/to/your/folder1', '/path/to/some/file.txt'], ['/path/to/destination/folder', '/path/to/another/folder']);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [shelljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs)

`npm i -D shelljs`

```
const bash = require('shelljs');
bash.cp("-rf", "/path/to/source/folder", "/path/to/destination/folder");
```

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript version

```
async function copyDir(source: string, destination: string): Promise<any> {
  const directoryEntries = await readdir(source, { withFileTypes: true });
  await mkdir(destination, { recursive: true });

  return Promise.all(
    directoryEntries.map(async (entry) => {
      const sourcePath = path.join(source, entry.name);
      const destinationPath = path.join(destination, entry.name);

      return entry.isDirectory()
        ? copyDir(sourcePath, destinationPath)
        : copyFile(sourcePath, destinationPath);
    })
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I'm just building a simple Node.js script, I didn't want the users of the script to need to import a bunch of external modules and dependencies, so I put on my thinking cap and did a search for running commands from the Bash shell.

This Node.js code snippet recursively copies a folder called node-webkit.app to a folder called build:

```
child = exec("cp -r node-webkit.app build", function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    sys.print("stdout: " + stdout);
    sys.print("stderr: " + stderr);
    if(error !== null) {
        console.log("exec error: " + error);
    } else {

    }
});
```

Thanks to [Lance Pollard at dzone](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/execute-unix-command-nodejs) for getting me started.

The above snippet is limited to Unix-based platforms, like macOS and Linux, but a similar technique may work for Windows.

Comment: A similar snippet does exist for windows, as referenced here: https://www.windows-commandline.com/copy-directory-command-line/.  The command is `Xcopy /E /I <sourcedir> <destdir>`.  Follow the reference to understand the command-prompt command.

Comment: You could use `which cp` and `where xcopy` to determine which to use. But this becomes lengthy and isn't really copying using node.

Answer (score 1):

This code will work just fine, recursively copying any folder to any location. But it is Windows only.

```
var child = require("child_process");
function copySync(from, to){
    from = from.replace(/\//gim, "\\");
    to = to.replace(/\//gim, "\\");
    child.exec("xcopy /y /q \"" + from + "\\*\" \"" + to + "\\\"");
}
```

It works perfectly for my textbased game for creating new players.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux, and performance is not an issue, you may use the `exec` function from `child_process` module, to execute a Bash command:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('cp -r source dest', (error, stdout, stderr) => {...});
```

In some cases, I found this solution cleaner than downloading an entire module or even using the `fs` module.

Comment: As many comments already noted on previous solutions: this is not cross-platform!

Comment: The OP didn't ask for a cross platform solution, and I've already pointed out that this is only for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy all contents of source directory recursively then you need to pass `recursive` option as `true` and `try` `catch` is documented way by fs-extra for `sync`

As `fs-extra` is complete replacement of `fs` so you don't need to import the base module

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
let sourceDir = '/tmp/src_dir';
let destDir = '/tmp/dest_dir';
try {
  fs.copySync(sourceDir, destDir, { recursive: true })
  console.log('success!')
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For older node versions that don't have [`fs.cp`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fscpsrc-dest-options-callback), I'm using this in a pinch to avoid requiring a third-party library:

```js
const fs = require("fs").promises;
const path = require("path");

const cp = async (src, dest) => {
  const lstat = await fs.lstat(src).catch(err => false);

  if (!lstat) {
    return;
  }
  else if (await lstat.isFile()) {
    await fs.copyFile(src, dest);
  }
  else if (await lstat.isDirectory()) {
    await fs.mkdir(dest).catch(err => {});

    for (const f of await fs.readdir(src)) {
      await cp(path.join(src, f), path.join(dest, f));
    }
  }
};

// sample usage
(async () => {
  const src = "foo";
  const dst = "bar";

  for (const f of await fs.readdir(src)) {
    await cp(path.join(src, f), path.join(dst, f));
  }
})();
```

Advantages (or differentiators) relative to existing answers:

- async
- ignores symbolic links
- doesn't throw if a directory already exists (don't catch the `mkdir` throw if this is undesirable)
- fairly succinct

Answer (score 1):

This could be a possible solution using async generator function and iterating over with `for await` loop. This solution includes the possibility to filter out some directories passing them as an optional third array argument.

```
import path from 'path';
import { readdir, copy } from 'fs-extra';

async function* getFilesRecursive(srcDir: string, excludedDir?: PathLike[]): AsyncGenerator<string> {
  const directoryEntries: Dirent[] = await readdir(srcDir, { withFileTypes: true });
  if (!directoryEntries.length) yield srcDir; // If the directory is empty, return the directory path.
  for (const entry of directoryEntries) {
    const fileName = entry.name;
      const sourcePath = resolvePath(`${srcDir}/${fileName}`);
      if (entry.isDirectory()) {
        if (!excludedDir?.includes(sourcePath)) {
          yield* getFilesRecursive(sourcePath, excludedDir);
        }
      } else {
        yield sourcePath;
      }
  }
}
```

Then:

```
for await (const filePath of getFilesRecursive(path, ['dir1', 'dir2'])) {
   await copy(filePath, filePath.replace(path, path2));
}
```

Comment: fs.cp is built in to current Node

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
let fs = require('fs');
let path = require('path');
```

Then:

```
let filePath = // Your file path

let fileList = []
    var walkSync = function(filePath, filelist)
    {
        let files = fs.readdirSync(filePath);
        filelist = filelist || [];
        files.forEach(function(file)
        {
            if (fs.statSync(path.join(filePath, file)).isDirectory())
            {
                filelist = walkSync(path.join(filePath, file), filelist);
            }
            else
            {
                filelist.push(path.join(filePath, file));
            }
        });

        // Ignore hidden files
        filelist = filelist.filter(item => !(/(^|\/)\.[^\/\.]/g).test(item));

        return filelist;
    };
```

Then call the method:

```
This.walkSync(filePath, fileList)
```

Answer (score 0):

The current top answer can be greatly simplified.

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

function recursiveCopySync(source, target) {
  if (fs.lstatSync(source).isDirectory()) {
    if (!fs.existsSync(target)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(target);
    }
    let files = fs.readdirSync(source);
    files.forEach((file) => {
      recursiveCopySync(path.join(source, file), path.join(target, file));
    });
  } else {
    if (fs.existsSync(source)) {
      fs.writeFileSync(target, fs.readFileSync(source));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline version

```
node -e "const fs=require('fs');const p=require('path');function copy(src, dest) {if (!fs.existsSync(src)) {return;} if (fs.statSync(src).isFile()) {fs.copyFileSync(src, dest);}else{fs.mkdirSync(dest, {recursive: true});fs.readdirSync(src).forEach(f=>copy(p.join(src, f), p.join(dest, f)));}}const args=Array.from(process.argv); copy(args[args.length-2], args[args.length-1]);" dist temp\dest
```

or node 16.x+

```
node -e "const fs=require('fs');const args=Array.from(process.argv); fs.cpSync(args[args.length-2], args[args.length-1], {recursive: true});"
```

Tested on "node 14.20.0", but assuming it works on node 10.x?

> From user8894303 and mpen's answers:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52338335/458321

Be sure to \" escape quotes if using in package.json script

package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "rmrf": "node -e \"const fs=require('fs/promises');const args=Array.from(process.argv); Promise.allSettled(args.map(a => fs.rm(a, { recursive: true, force: true })));\"",
    "cp": "node -e \"const fs=require('fs');const args=Array.from(process.argv);if (args.length>2){ fs.cpSync(args[args.length-2], args[args.length-1], {recursive: true});}else{console.log('args missing', args);}\""
    "copy": "node -e \"const fs=require('fs');const p=require('path');function copy(src, dest) {if (!fs.existsSync(src)) {return;} if (fs.statSync(src).isFile()) {fs.copyFileSync(src, dest);}else{fs.mkdirSync(dest, {recursive: true});fs.readdirSync(src).forEach(f=>copy(p.join(src, f), p.join(dest, f)));}}const args=Array.from(process.argv);if (args.length>2){copy(args[args.length-2], args[args.length-1]);}else{console.log('args missing', args);}\"",
    "mkdir": "node -e \"const fs=require('fs');const args=Array.from(process.argv);fs.mkdirSync(args[args.length-1],{recursive:true});\"",
    "clean": "npm run rmrf -- temp && npm run mkdir -- temp && npm run copy -- dist temp"
  }
```

note: rmrf script requires node 14.20.x or 12.20.x?

bonus:

```
deno eval "import { existsSync, mkdirSync, copyFileSync, readdirSync, statSync } from 'node:fs';import { join } from 'node:path';function copy(src, dest) {if (!existsSync(src)) {return;} if (statSync(src).isFile()) {copyFileSync(src, dest);}else{mkdirSync(dest, {recursive: true});readdirSync(src).forEach(f=>copy(join(src, f), join(dest, f)));}}const args=Array.from(Deno.args);copy(args[0], args[1]);" dist temp\dest -- --allow-read --allow-write
```

[deno](https://deno.land/) support -> `npm i deno-bin` for [deno-bin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deno-bin) support in node

Comment: native alternative to fs-copy-file-sync, copyfiles, fs-extra, etc...

Comment: copy doesn't support glob matching yet. Neither does rmrf.

Comment: Glad I made this answer. I have came back to it like 20 times or so. Not specifically above. Just "script-name": "`node -e \"[script]\" "` and now to pass arguments via  `npm run script-name -- argument1 argument2`

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but for builds, it's sometimes nice to have options around what to do - this adds three modes:

- `create` (fails if target exists)
- `merge` (merges files into existing folders if found)
- `replace` (hammer time: blows away the target if it exists already)

```js
/**
 Copies the provided folder to a new location.
 In the default mode (`create`), files are copied to the target
 path by default, but other modes to merge and replace are supported
 by setting the `mode` value on the `options` parameter.

 @param {string} from Folder to copy from.
 @param {string} to Folder to copy to.
 @param {{mode:'merge'|'replace'|'create'; }} options Options for the copy:

   `mode` - operation to perform; one of:
     - `merge`: files are merged into any existing folder structure
     - `replace`: any existing folder structure is replaced
     - `create`: (default) the target folder must not yet exist
 */
function copyFolderSync(from, to, options) {
    const {mode} = {
        mode: 'create',
        ...options,
    };

    // If replace, ensure target is gone.
    if (mode === 'replace') {
        fs.rmSync(to, {force:true, recursive: true});
    }

    // If target does not exist, create it
    if (!fs.existsSync(to)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(to);
    }
    else if (mode === 'create') {
        // Can't overwrite - throw
        throw new Error(
            `Cannot copy to ${to} because it exists already.`);
    }
    else if (!fs.lstatSync(to).isDirectory()) {
        // Exists (so op !== 'replace') and is not a folder so can't merge
        throw new Error(
            `Cannot copy to ${to} because it exists already and is not a folder.`);
    }
    fs.readdirSync(from).forEach(itemName => {
        const itemInfo = fs.lstatSync(path.join(from, itemName));
        if (itemInfo.isFile()) {
            fs.copyFileSync(path.join(from, itemName), path.join(to, itemName));
        }
        else if (itemInfo.isDirectory()) {
            copyFolderSync(path.join(from, itemName),
                path.join(to, itemName), options);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

### Yes, `ncp` is `cool` though...

You might want/should promisify its function to make it `super cool`. While you're at it, add it to a `tools` file to reuse it.

Below is a working version which is `Async` and uses `Promises`.

---

#### File *index.js*

```
const {copyFolder} = require('./tools/');

return copyFolder(
    yourSourcePath,
    yourDestinationPath
)
.then(() => {
    console.log('-> Backup completed.')
}) .catch((err) => {
    console.log("-> [ERR] Could not copy the folder: ", err);
})
```

#### File *tools.js*

```
const ncp = require("ncp");

/**
 * Promise Version of ncp.ncp()
 *
 * This function promisifies ncp.ncp().
 * We take the asynchronous function ncp.ncp() with
 * callback semantics and derive from it a new function with
 * promise semantics.
 */
ncp.ncpAsync = function (sourcePath, destinationPath) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      try {
          ncp.ncp(sourcePath, destinationPath, function(err){
              if (err) reject(err); else resolve();
          });
      } catch (err) {
          reject(err);
      }
  });
};

/**
 * Utility function to copy folders asynchronously using
 * the Promise returned by ncp.ncp().
 */
const copyFolder = (sourcePath, destinationPath) => {
    return ncp.ncpAsync(sourcePath, destinationPath, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
    });
}
module.exports.copyFolder = copyFolder;
```

Answer (score -2):

The easiest approach for this problem is to use only the 'fs' and 'Path' module and some logic...

All files in the root folder copy with the *new name* if you want to just set the version number, i.e., *" var v = 'Your Directory Name'"*

In the file name prefix with content added with the file name.

```
var fs = require('fs-extra');
var path = require('path');

var c = 0;
var i = 0;
var v = "1.0.2";
var copyCounter = 0;
var directoryCounter = 0;
var directoryMakerCounter = 0;
var recursionCounter = -1;
var Flag = false;
var directoryPath = [];
var directoryName = [];
var directoryFileName = [];
var fileName;
var directoryNameStorer;
var dc = 0;
var route;

if (!fs.existsSync(v)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(v);
}

var basePath = path.join(__dirname, v);


function walk(dir) {

    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, items) {

        items.forEach(function(file) {

            file = path.resolve(dir, file);

            fs.stat(file, function(err, stat) {

                if(stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
                    directoryNameStorer = path.basename(file);
                    route = file;
                    route = route.replace("gd", v);

                    directoryFileName[directoryCounter] = route;
                    directoryPath[directoryCounter] = file;
                    directoryName[directoryCounter] = directoryNameStorer;

                    directoryCounter++;
                    dc++;

                    if (!fs.existsSync(basePath + "/" + directoryName[directoryMakerCounter])) {
                        fs.mkdirSync(directoryFileName[directoryMakerCounter]);
                        directoryMakerCounter++;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    fileName = path.basename(file);
                    if(recursionCounter >= 0) {
                        fs.copyFileSync(file, directoryFileName[recursionCounter] + "/" + v + "_" + fileName, err => {
                            if(err) return console.error(err);
                        });
                        copyCounter++;
                    }
                    else {
                        fs.copyFileSync(file, v + "/" + v + "_" + fileName, err => {
                            if(err) return console.error(err);
                        });
                        copyCounter++;
                    }
                }
                if(copyCounter + dc == items.length && directoryCounter > 0 && recursionCounter < directoryMakerCounter-1) {
                    console.log("COPY COUNTER:             " + copyCounter);
                    console.log("DC COUNTER:               " + dc);
                    recursionCounter++;
                    dc = 0;
                    copyCounter = 0;
                    console.log("ITEM DOT LENGTH:          " + items.length);
                    console.log("RECURSION COUNTER:        " + recursionCounter);
                    console.log("DIRECOTRY MAKER COUNTER:  " + directoryMakerCounter);
                    console.log(": START RECURSION:        " + directoryPath[recursionCounter]);
                    walk(directoryPath[recursionCounter]); //recursive call to copy sub-folder
                }
            })
        })
    });
}

walk('./gd', function(err, data) { // Just pass the root directory which you want to copy
    if(err)
        throw err;
    console.log("done");
})
```