# Node fs copy a folder

Tags: node.js, fs

I am trying to copy a folder using Node `fs` module. I am familiar with `readFileSync()` and `writeFileSync()` methods but I am wondering what method I should use to copy a specified folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy folder recursively in node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786160/copy-folder-recursively-in-node-js)

Answer (score 39):

You can use [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) to copy contents of one folder to another like this

```
var fs = require("fs-extra");

fs.copy('/path/to/source', '/path/to/destination', function (err) {
  if (err) return console.error(err)
  console.log('success!')
});
```

There's also a synchronous version.

```
fs.copySync('/path/to/source', '/path/to/destination')
```

Answer (score 35):

Save yourself the extra dependency with just 10 lines of native node functions

Add the following `copyDir` function:

```js
const { promises: fs } = require("fs")
const path = require("path")

async function copyDir(src, dest) {
    let entries = await fs.readdir(src, { recursive: true, withFileTypes: true })

    for (let entry of entries) {
        let srcPath = path.join(entry.path, entry.name);
        let destPath = srcPath.replace(src, dest);
        let destDir = path.dirname(destPath);
        
        if (entry.isFile()) {
            await fs.mkdir(destDir, { recursive: true })
            await fs.copyFile(srcPath, destPath);
        }
    }
}
```

And then use like this:

```js
copyDir("./inputFolder", "./outputFolder")
```

With [recursive readdir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77512570/1366033) as of v20.1.0, v18.17.0 (May 2023+).  See previous revision if not updated yet.

#### Further Reading

- [Copy folder recursively in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13786160/1366033)
- [`fsPromises.copyFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_copyfile_src_dest_mode) <sup>(added in `v10.11.0`)</sup>
- [`fsPromises.readdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readdir_path_options) <sup>(added in `v10.0`)</sup>
- [`fsPromises.mkdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_mkdir_path_options) <sup>(added in `v10.0`)</sup>

Comment: I really like the idea of avoiding the extra dependencies.  I think that few of us actually realise the capabilities that are inherent in "vanilla node".

Comment: Amazing approach, thanks man!

Comment: Thanks man, this is amazing, avoid glob, fs-extra, and other dependencies using this stuff, you're my hero!

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check out the [ncp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ncp) package. It does exactly what you're trying to do; Recursively copy files from a path to another.

Here's something to get your started :

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const ncp = require("ncp").ncp;
// No limit, because why not?
ncp.limit = 0;

var thePath = "./";
var folder = "testFolder";
var newFolder = "newTestFolder";

ncp(path.join(thePath, folder), path.join(thePath, newFolder), function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
    console.log("Done !");
});
```

Comment: Why would someone choose `ncp` over `fs-extra`?

Comment: There are plenty of reasons to choose one tool over another. Back when I wrote that answer, it was the package I prefered for accomplishing that task. Nowadays it might be better to use `fs-extra`, but that doesn't mean my answer was bad at the time I wrote it.

Comment: I was not insinuating your answer was bad. I was just curious for myself. Thanks

Comment: ncp can copy files in a folder recursively whereas fs-extra only copies files directly under the folder

Comment: fs-extra also copies all the files recursively just like ncp does. I don't see any difference between them in terms of copying a folder.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the synchronous version of [@KyleMit answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64255382/237917)

```
copyDirectory(source, destination) {
    fs.mkdirSync(destination, { recursive: true });
    
    fs.readdirSync(source, { withFileTypes: true }).forEach((entry) => {
      let sourcePath = path.join(source, entry.name);
      let destinationPath = path.join(destination, entry.name);

      entry.isDirectory()
        ? copyDirectory(sourcePath, destinationPath)
        : fs.copyFileSync(sourcePath, destinationPath);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I liked [KyleMit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64255382/12354596), but thought a parallel version would be preferable.

The code is in TypeScript. If you need JavaScript, just delete the `: string` type annotations on the line of the declaration of `copyDirectory`.

```
import { promises as fs } from "fs"
import path from "path"

export const copyDirectory = async (src: string, dest: string) => {
  const [entries] = await Promise.all([
    fs.readdir(src, { withFileTypes: true }),
    fs.mkdir(dest, { recursive: true }),
  ])

  await Promise.all(
    entries.map((entry) => {
      const srcPath = path.join(src, entry.name)
      const destPath = path.join(dest, entry.name)
      return entry.isDirectory()
        ? copyDirectory(srcPath, destPath)
        : fs.copyFile(srcPath, destPath)
    })
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an elegant syntax. You can use the [pwd-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pwd-fs) module.

```
const FileSystem = require('pwd-fs');
const pfs = new FileSystem();

async () => {
  await pfs.copy('./path', './dest');
}
```