# Node.js recursively list full path of files

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, filesystems, electron

Good night everyone. I'm having trouble with probably some simple recursive function. The problem is to recursively list all files in a given folder and its subfolders.

For the moment, I've managed to list files in a directory using a simple function:

```js
fs.readdirSync(copyFrom).forEach((file) => {
  let fullPath = path.join(copyFrom, file);

  if (fs.lstatSync(fullPath).isDirectory()) {
    console.log(fullPath);
  } else {
    console.log(fullPath);
  }
});
```

I've tried various methods like `do{} ... while()` but I can't get it right. As I'm a beginner in javascript, I finally decided to ask for help from you guys.

Comment: You can use `recursive-readdir` package for this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/recursive-readdir

Comment: I would say Good day to you from another timezone and that you should maybe also read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: Thanks @Kirill, I'll give it a try but as recursive functions seemed to be quite common I would have liked to understand how to do it :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just add a recursive call and you are done:

```
 function traverseDir(dir) {
   fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(file => {
     let fullPath = path.join(dir, file);
     if (fs.lstatSync(fullPath).isDirectory()) {
        traverseDir(fullPath);
     }  
     console.log(fullPath);
   });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to do the trick. However, I'm not having any console messages when executing the function... I must have missed something.

Comment: @YouDeserveThat, maybe a dumb question, but are you actually calling the function and not just defining it?

Comment: Hm. Dumb questions often help beginners :D. Thanks @FissureKing !

Comment: @YouDeserveThat Just call the function like: `traverseDir(copyFrom);`. Also, accept the answer if it solves your problem :D

Comment: Thanks so much all of you, you saved my night ;)

Comment: @JonasW. a perfect use case for `unfold` <3

Comment: Don't forget to import path `var path = require('path');`

Answer (score 4):

Using `console.log` in this way displays the path and that's great, but what if you want to do something more meaningful with the paths? For example, maybe you want to collect all of them in an array and pass them off for processing elsewhere...

This process of beginning with a seed state and expanding a sequence of values while the state changes is called an `unfold`.

```
const { join } =
  require ('path')

const { readdirSync, statSync } =
  require ('fs')

const unfold = (f, initState) =>
  f ( (value, nextState) => [ value, ...unfold (f, nextState) ]
    , () => []
    , initState
    )

const None =
  Symbol ()

const relativePaths = (path = '.') =>
  readdirSync (path) .map (p => join (path, p))

const traverseDir = (dir) =>
  unfold
    ( (next, done, [ path = None, ...rest ]) =>
        path === None
          ? done ()
          : next ( path
                 , statSync (path) .isDirectory ()
                     ? relativePaths (path) .concat (rest)
                     : rest
                 )
    , relativePaths (dir)
    )

console.log (traverseDir ('.'))
// [ a, a/1, a/1/1, a/2, a/2/1, a/2/2, b, b/1, ... ]
```

If this is your first time seeing a program like this, `unfold` will feel very overwhelming. Below, is a simplified example of `unfold` used to generate an array of the lowercase `alphabet`

```js
const unfold = (f, init) =>
  f ( (x, next) => [ x, ...unfold (f, next) ]
    , () => []
    , init
    )

const nextLetter = c =>
  String.fromCharCode (c.charCodeAt (0) + 1)

const alphabet =
  unfold
    ( (next, done, c) =>
        c > 'z'
          ? done ()
          : next ( c              // value to add to output
                 , nextLetter (c) // next state
                 )
    , 'a' // initial state
    )

console.log (alphabet)
// [ a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z ]
```

If you're still stuck, the techniques I've demonstrated here are explained in greater detail in answers to similar questions

- [*Functional way to create an array of numbers*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50109309/633183)
- [*Loop until... with Ramda*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49543489/633183)

Generally, it's preferred to use the asynchronous functions in the `fs` module as this prevents the program from hanging in the event of long disk read times or network delay. Unfolding plays nicely with asynchrony as demonstrated in these other Q&A's

- [*Recursive Promises Not Returning*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50121218/633183)
- [*Recursion call async func with promises gets Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49681942/633183)
- [*Recursive JS function with setTimeout*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49523873/633183)
- [*Promise with recursion*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49526214/633183)

Comment: Thanks for the really detailed anwser, I'll give it a try tomorrow :)

Comment: @YouDeserveThat my pleasure. I've recently learned about [anamorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anamorphism) and I see use cases for them everywhere now! Let me know if you have any questions, I'm happy to help :D

Answer (score 1):

I am using following `getFilesTree` function. This function recursively list all files in a directory and its subdirectories except hidden folders and files (start's with `.`).

```js
import {readdir} from 'node:fs/promises';
import {join, resolve} from 'node:path';
import {parse} from 'node:path';

export async function getFilesTree(dir) {
    return await Promise.all(
        (await readdir(dir, {withFileTypes: true}))
            .filter(child => !child.name.startsWith('.')) // skip hidden
            .map(async (child) => {
                const base = parse(child.name).base;
                const path = resolve(dir, child.name);
                return child.isDirectory() ?
                    {base, path, children: await getFilesTree(join(dir, child.name))} :
                    {base, path};
            }),
    );
}
```

Function itself is very similar to the [recursive-readdir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/recursive-readdir) library. The results then look something like this:

```json
[
    {
        "base": "file.js",
        "path": "/Volumes/Work/file.js"
    },
    {
        "base": "css",
        "path": "/Volumes/Work/css",
        "children": [
            {
                "base": "index.css",
                "path": "/Volumes/Work/css/index.css"
            },
            {
                "base": "code.css",
                "path": "/Volumes/Work/css/code.css"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Sometimes there is no need to have the structured data, then you can use [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) instead:

```js
import {readdir} from 'node:fs/promises';
import {resolve} from 'node:path';

async function * getFiles(dir) {
    for (const dirent of await readdir(dir, {withFileTypes: true})) {
        const res = resolve(dir, dirent.name);
        if (dirent.isDirectory()) {
            yield * getFiles(res);
        } else {
            yield res;
        }
    }
}

for await (const file of getFiles('content')) {
    console.log(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking off Jonas Wilms answer - that turned out to be really slow for a large number of files. This is faster (though it is async).

```
const getFilesnamesRecursive = (dir: string, foundFiles: string[]) => {
const files = fs.readdirSync(dir, {withFileTypes: true});
files.forEach((entry: any) =>{        
    if (entry.isDirectory()){                    
        getFilesnamesRecursive(path.join(dir, entry.name)), foundFiles, logger);
    }
    else{            
        foundFiles.push(path.join(dir, entry.name);
    }
});
```

}

The other is slower because it was using readdir to get each filename **then** checking if it was a directory. This way is faster because it users the option withFileTypes: true to return each entry as a [Dirent object](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#class-fsdirent), instead of just the filename.

Answer (score 0):

### Update [v20.1.0](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v20.1.0), [v18.17.0](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v18.17.0) (May 2023+)

This is now natively supported like this:

```js
const fs = require('fs').promises;

const files = await fs.readdir(".", { recursive: true })
```

**Futher Reading**:

- [Docs on **fs readdir options**](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesreaddirpath-options)
- [PR #41439 - fs: add recursive opendir/readdir](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/41439)
- [Node.js fs.readdir recursive directory search](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5827612/1366033)
- [Get all files recursively in directories NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41462606/1366033)