# I wonder if with (fs) I can copy a folder from one location to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Is there a method to copy a folder from one place to another?

I used the method:

fs.copyFileSync()

However, it copies only files.

Is there a way for me to copy a folder from one location to another?

Comment: folder, with or without sub-folders? you'll nee to write some actual code either way

Comment: The `fs` module itself does not have this capability.  There are numerous 3rd party modules that offer features like this like [fs-extra](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/HEAD/docs/copy.md).

Comment: I would like to copy folder from the desktop to another folder in case @jaromanda-x

Comment: Tks @jfriend00, obrigado!

Comment: yes, and you'll need to write code in that case too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy folder recursively in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786160/copy-folder-recursively-in-node-js)

Comment: Also, answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40019824/1563833

Answer (score 0):

you can use exec function to execute an os command

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('cp -r <sorceFolderPath> <destFolderPath>', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  }
```

this may differ with OS