# Add file to /res/values?

Tags: android, phonegap-cli

Is it possible to specify a file to be added to the Android /res/values folder?

I am trying to add a custom theme to change the appearance of the native input pickers, such as `<input type="date">`. I found the [cordova-custom-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-custom-config) plugin that lets me set the theme in AndroidManifest.xml, but that doesnt do anything for actually adding the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

I added a hook to the android platform in config.xml

```
<hook type="before_prepare" src="scripts/020_copy_resources.js" />
```

In the hook, I ran a script based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26038979/1269846), saved in `<project>/scripts/020_copy_resources.js"`

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// Native resources to copy
var androidNativePath = 'native/android/';

// Android platform resource path
var androidResPath = 'platforms/android/res/';

// Copy native resources
var rootdir = process.argv[2];

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

function copyFileSync( source, target ) {

    var targetFile = target;

    //if target is a directory a new file with the same name will be created
    if ( fs.existsSync( target ) ) {
        if ( fs.lstatSync( target ).isDirectory() ) {
            targetFile = path.join( target, path.basename( source ) );
        }
    }
    process.stdout.write('Copying ' + source + ' to ' + targetFile);
    fs.writeFileSync(targetFile, fs.readFileSync(source));
}

function copyFolderRecursiveSync( source, target ) {
    var files = [];

    //check if folder needs to be created or integrated
    //var targetFolder = path.join( target, path.basename( source ) );
    var targetFolder = target;
    if ( !fs.existsSync( targetFolder ) ) {
        fs.mkdirSync( targetFolder );
        process.stdout.write('fs.mkdirSync( ' + targetFolder + ' )');
    }

    //copy
    if ( fs.lstatSync( source ).isDirectory() ) {
        files = fs.readdirSync( source );
        files.forEach( function ( file ) {
            var curSource = path.join( source, file );
            if ( fs.lstatSync( curSource ).isDirectory() ) {
                var newTarget = path.join( targetFolder, path.basename( curSource ) );
                copyFolderRecursiveSync( curSource, newTarget );
                process.stdout.write('copyFolderRecursiveSync(' + curSource + ', ' + newTarget + ' )');
            } else {
                copyFileSync( curSource, targetFolder );
                process.stdout.write('copyFileSync(' + curSource + ', ' + targetFolder + ' )');
            }
        } );
    }
}

if (rootdir) {
    copyFolderRecursiveSync(androidNativePath, androidResPath);
    process.stdout.write('Copied android native resources');
}
```

This copies any files/folders in `<project>/native/android` to `<project>/platforms/android/res`

I then followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29014475/1269846) to build the theme for the date picker. For my purposes, I only needed to set the `colorAccent` and `colorBackground` in the main theme and the `datePickerDialogTheme`.