# Copy folder content to another folder with nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm looking for a way to copy a folder's content to another folder or even replace the folder if it exists with the old one but preserve its name.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: **See Also**: [Copy folder recursively in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13786160/1366033)

Answer (score 5):

First install `fs-extra` module in your project by doing `npm install fs-extra` then follow the steps below:

import the following

```
var fs = require('fs');
var fs_Extra = require('fs-extra');
var path = require('path');
```

// Here you declare your path

```
var sourceDir = path.join(__dirname, "../working");
var destinationDir = path.join(__dirname, "../worked")
```

// if folder doesn't exists create it

```
if (!fs.existsSync(destinationDir)){
    fs.mkdirSync(destinationDir, { recursive: true });
}
```

// copy folder content

```
fs_Extra.copy(sourceDir, destinationDir, function(error) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    } else {
      console.log("success!");
    }
});
```

NB: source and destination folder name should not be the same.

Comment: This only copies the directory and not it's contents

Answer (score 4):

First check if the destination path exists if not create it, 
then you could use fs-extra for the copying of files/subdirectories.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var fse = require('fs-extra');

var sourceDir = '/tmp/mydir';
var destDir = '/tmp/mynewdir';


// if folder doesn't exists create it
if (!fs.existsSync(destDir)){
    fs.mkdirSync(destDir, { recursive: true });
}

//copy directory content including subfolders
fse.copy(sourceDir, destDir, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log("success!");
  }
});
```

Comment: What if we only want to copy the files and not recreate the folder structure? How can we do that?